# jQuery function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, undefined

My function here is ever returnig undefined, what is wrong?

```
    function getTaxType() {
            $('.type').each(function() {
                if ($(this).data('tax') === 'form1' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                    return 'form1';
                }
                else if ($(this).data('tax') === 'form2' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                    return 'form2';
                }
                else if ($(this).data('tax') === 'form3' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                    return 'form3';
                }
            });
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling the function?

Comment: Did you try debugging in Chrome or Firefox by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: If none of your if statements are being met, then none of the return statements will be executed.

Comment: You can't return from a callback like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you're returning from the callback function of `$.each` and not from `getTaxType`.

Try this:

```
function getTaxType() {
    var result;
    $('.type').each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('tax') === 'form1' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
            result = 'form1';
        }
        else if ($(this).data('tax') === 'form2' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
             result =  'form2';
        }
        else if ($(this).data('tax') === 'form3' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
             result =  'form3';
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's checkboxes there can be more than one which means you have multiple results - storing this in array for you.

### Multiple-Choice:

```
function getTaxType() {
    var result = [];
    $('.type:checked').each(function(i) {
        var tax = $(this).data('tax');
        result[i] = (tax === 'form1' || tax === 'form2' || tax === 'form3') ? tax : false;
    });
    return result;
};
```

If you meant to only have one result (radio button), then you remove the `= []` on result and the `[i]` in the loop.

### Single Answer

```
function getTaxType() {
    var tax = $('.type:checked').data('tax');
    var result = (tax === 'form1' || tax === 'form2' || tax === 'form3') ? tax : false;
    return result;
};
```

Of course, if it is single answer (aka radio buttons) then you can ONLY have those three form answers which makes it even simpler:

```
function getTaxType() {
    return $('.type:checked').data('tax');
};
```